# Debug Android internal API about Sim Toolkit and UI

Tags: java, android, api, internals, sim-toolkit

I am working on a project where the client wants to make automatic tests of UI components (e.g. using Appium or UI Automator), the project is based on the SIM Toolkit.

The aim is to test if GUI components are displayed (thanks to commands sent to a SIM applet).

However, the system does not permit to check if objects from internal APIs are displayed (basically a SIM Menu).

My question is: how can I test these internal objects automaticaly? Is there a flag I can pull down to say to the system "hey let me test this component you try to hide" ? Basically I guess the system does not allow to handle these components for security reasons.